# how to make 2d graphic in java without repaint()?

Tags: java, graphics, 2d-games

i want to draw some rectangles in different timesets, when i draw first rectangle by paint(), i use paint() to draw second one then a first rectangle disappear. I found that an image was override a previos one. How can i do without recreating previous ones(like not using repaint())? i appreciate every answer:d

```
public static class Screen extends Frame 
    {

        int WIDTH = 900;
        static int[][] map = new int[700][700];
        public Screen() 
        {
            super("Clash of Tank");
            setSize(WIDTH, WIDTH);
            addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() 
            {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
        }


        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) createImage(700,700);
            Graphics g2 = image.getGraphics();
            drawTank(g2);
            g.drawImage(image, 325, 35, this);
        }


        void drawTank(Graphics g) {

            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            for(int i = 0; i<=690; i+=1)
                for(int j = 0; j<=690; j+=1)
                    {
                        if(map[i][j]==0)
                            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        if((map[i][j]==1))
                            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                        if((map[i][j]==2))
                            g.setColor(Color.RED);
                        if((map[i][j]==3))
                            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                        if((map[i][j]==4))
                            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        g.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
                    }



        }

    }


public class ClashofTanks 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        Screen t = new Screen(); 
        t.setVisible(true);
        t.repaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yours is a classic [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask for a specific solution to solve a wrong way to do something.

The key is that you **should** use `repaint()`, but that you should either store a collection of Rectangles and draw them in a for loop in your `paint` or `paintComponent` method (if using Swing), or else draw them to a BufferedImage and draw *that* in the painting method. Don't forget to also call your super paint or paintComponent method.